# How to Calculate/Determine Efficiency of Real Energy Conversion Devices/Machines?

Tags: thermodynamics

When we analyze working of energy conversion machines such as engines or batteries, we usually first consider the case in which our machines work reversibly since such working is the most easy to analyze and gives us the biggest value of efficiency we can theorethically obtain.

No real machine works reversibly and its efficiency is always lower than for revesible one.

How can we calcualte/measure efficiency of real energy conversion devices since measurement of entropy generated in the system isn't something I know we can experimentaly measure or calculate?

How do engineers do this in practice?

Comment: I don't care about how much entropy is generated, I care about how much  energy/work I can get out of the system. So I can charge a battery and then discharge it into a load and measure the conversion efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

> How can we calculate/measure efficiency of real energy conversion
> devices since measurement of entropy generated in the system isn't
> something I know we can experimentally measure or calculate

There is no need to measure the entropy generated in order to determine the actual efficiency of an energy conversion device, only the maximum theoretical efficiency.

For any energy conversion device its efficiency equals the desired energy output divided by the required energy input. If it's an electric motor, it's the mechanical output (HP, watts) divided by the electrical energy input (watts). If it's a heat engine it's the work output divided by the gross heat added. And so forth.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. So, if we take an engine, we need to measure work done in one cycle for example. How can we calculate real work done without knowing entropy generated since in order to calculate it we need to know that? Only thing that comes to my mind is to measure it experimentally. Maybe we can connect engine to some weight and than use the engine to lift it up at constant velocity. So work done would be difference in potential energy of the weight.

Comment: You don't need to know the entropy generated. Calculating the actual efficiency is a first law application, not second law. And of course you would need to make appropriate measurements, an example of which to just gave at the end. So I'm really not sure what your issue is. Perhaps you can give a concrete example of not being able to determine efficiency without knowing entropy generated.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You don't neccessarily need to know entropy generated to calculate irreversible state changes. To calculate work or heat, we need to know how state change is carried or how much does state change deviate from reversible change.